# Persisting an object using JPA with predetermined ID

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I need to `persist()` an object with an `id`, that I can specify. However I can't annotate the base class with a different `@GeneratedValue`. Can you assign a value generator just for a single persist? I have a specific use, please don't tell me that the id shouldn't be set manually.

Is there a way this can be done with JPA? Appreciate any hints!

[edited] `@GeneratedValue` annotation is present in the base class

Answer (score 2):

`@GeneratedValue` is precisely used to tell JPA that it should generate the ID. If you want to assign the ID explicitely and don't want JPA to generate one for you, just don't use the `@GeneratedValue` annotation, assign the ID explicitely, and call `persist()`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, this works. However is there a way to change this behavior without changing the class definition just for a single persist? I guess not?